# PyQt4 calling Method from another Class

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, pyqt4

I got Class A with the method i want to call.

```
class Class_A(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, database, tableName):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dbu = database_manager_2.DatabaseUtility(database, tableName)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Class_A):
         ...

    def print_somethig (self):
           print 'hello'
```

This is class B :

```
class class B(object):              
    def setupUi_1(self, Dialog):
        ...
        self.my_instance = Class_A()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButtonSecond, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")),self.my_instance.print_something() )
```

As you can see i have created an instance from class A so i can call it's method in class B.

I got this error :

> TypeError: `__init__()` takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

I know this is something related to OOP.

Comment: I think the error message is rather self-explanatory. You need to supply the __init__ method with three variables when you instantiate the class: self, database, and tableName. Python takes care of the first one by itself - only two to go!

Comment: yeah but i think there must be some way to overcome this variable demand ,because after all i dont want to supply and DB ar table, i just want to call a method that is located within that class ,thats it .

Comment: @user3532371: I answered your question. There are just these 2 possibilities. But with your original signature, there is no way calling Class_A() will work.

Comment: I can confirm, it is the only possibility. Python doesn't provide the possibility to provide multiple constructors (such as for example C++), instead you always have ONE constructor. However you are still flexible in the amount of arguments you can provide by the use of default arguments, e.g. `init(self, x=None):`

Comment: @user3532371. What is the point of creating an instance of `Class_A` if it hasn't been initialised properly? What does the method you want to call actually do? If the method doesn't access any internal state of the class instance (such as the db or the ui components), maybe it should be a `classmethod` or `staticmethod` (in which case, you wouldn't need to create an instance).

Answer (score 1):

That's nothing related with OOP:

Your method signature is:

```
def __init__(self, database, tableName):
```

So if you call:
`a = Class_A()` you give just 1 parameter (self is implicitly given as a parameter).
There is no to overcome it. You could define default values like that:

```
def __init__(self, database=None, tableName=None):
```

So if you call:

```
a = Class_A()
```

database and tableName will be None. But then:

```
self.dbu = database_manager_2.DatabaseUtility(database, tableName)
```

throws an error I think.

But with your original method signature, there is no way around that.